# NoClassDefFoundError. How to fix it?

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm creating an Android app which uses the Microsoft Hawaii SDK to perform the OCR of a pic taken with the cellphone camera. I've an error during the execution of my Android app.
the log cat is this:

```
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.mobile.RecognitionActivity
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at com.example.mobile.FotocameraActivity.onActivityResult(FotocameraActivity.java:143)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4820)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2435)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1990)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3355)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1155)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
02-07 14:48:59.617: E/AndroidRuntime(24660):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code of FotocameraActivity.Java is this:

```
package com.example.mobile;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.GpsStatus.Listener;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FotocameraActivity extends Activity {


   // dati che servono per la fotocamera
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 100; // un numero a nostro
                                                                                                // piacimento
File tmpFotoFile = null;
byte[] bitmapdata;
ImageView preview;
LocationManager locationManager;
String gps;
final static String ARRAY_BYTE = "ARRAY_BYTE";
final static String GPS = "GPS";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        startGpsTracking();
        }

        try {
                launchCamera();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
}

private void startGpsTracking() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsListener);
         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 3, myLocationListener);
   }

private Listener gpsListener = new Listener(){
   public void onGpsStatusChanged(int status){
         switch(status){
         case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                Log.d(LOCATION_SERVICE,"onGpsStatusChanged First Fix");
                break;
         case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                Log.d(LOCATION_SERVICE, "onGpsStatusChanged Satellite");
                break;
         case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                Log.d(LOCATION_SERVICE, "onGpsStatusChanged Started");
                break;
         case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                Log.d(LOCATION_SERVICE, "onGpsStatusChanged Stopped");
                break;
         }
   }
};

private LocationListener myLocationListener = new LocationListener(){

         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                double lng = location.getLongitude(), lat = location.getLatitude();
                gps += String.format("%6f", lng) + "#" + String.format("%6f", lat); 

         }

         public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

         public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

         public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

};

   private void launchCamera() throws IOException {

        // Fase 1
        tmpFotoFile = File.createTempFile("OCRPic", null);

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); //Uri.fromFile(tmpFotoFile));
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                Bitmap datifoto = null;
                Uri picUri = data.getData();
                if(picUri != null){

                       try {
                              datifoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), picUri);
                              //datifoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);//Uri.fromFile(tmpFotoFile));
                              } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                              } catch (IOException e) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                              }
                }
                       ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                       datifoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);
                       bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
                       //tmpFotoFile.delete();

                SimpleView view = new SimpleView(this, datifoto); // creo l'istanza
                                                                                                                        // // della                                                                                                       // view...
                setContentView(view); // e la setto

                Intent intentRecognize = new Intent(this, RecognitionActivity.class); **<-Here refers the logcat for the error**
                intentRecognize.putExtra(ARRAY_BYTE, bitmapdata);
                intentRecognize.putExtra(GPS, gps);
                startActivity(intentRecognize);
        }

}
   }


class SimpleView extends View{

private Bitmap bitmap;
private Paint tmpPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

public SimpleView(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(context);
        this.bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,480,320,false);//ridimensiono l'immagine
}

@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
super.onDraw(canvas);
canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap, null , new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight()),tmpPaint);
}


}
```

While the code of RecognitionActivity.Java is this:

```
package com.example.mobile;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import microsoft.hawaii.sampleappbase.HawaiiBaseAuthActivity;


public class RecognitionActivity extends HawaiiBaseAuthActivity {

private TextView tv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recognition);

    tv.setText("Prova");
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_recognition, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I noticed that, in RecognitionActivity, if I extend that activity from Activity, it works, but if I extend HawaiiBaseAuthActivity, it crashes.

I noticed another message in the logcat, that appears just in the moment that the app starts:

```
02-07 14:48:14.717: E/dalvikvm(24660): Could not find class 'com.example.mobile.RecognitionActivity', referenced from method com.example.mobile.FotocameraActivity.onActivityResult
```

But that activity is defined in my workspace!

I will appreciate very much if someone can help me.

Comment: are these 2 in the same project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you added com.example.mobile.RecognitionActivity to the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes, it results added to the Manifest!

       <activity
            android:name="com.example.mobile.RecognitionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_recognition" >
        </activity>

Comment: Then clean your project and build again, it seems that in the final generated apk this class isnt packaged.

Comment: same comment as @akmsharma

Comment: I noticed you import:  microsoft.hawaii.sampleappbase.HawaiiBaseAuthActivity This is a library? Have you added to libs folder?

Comment: that is a project of Microsoft Hawaii, which is required in my own project; it is said on the documentation that i have to import that project. i tried to add the project in the build path, but it's always the same error. then i tried to add the resulting .jar in libs, but it doesn't change..

Comment: If the library project has resources, you need to add this project(s) in the Android tab of your project properties (Library references) and not like a .jar that you just drop on libraries folder or in the Java Build path.

Comment: I think i did how you told me. I've added on the build path the projects that were required (eclipse asked me if i wanted to add the projects or the .jars and i added the .jars).. now there is another error,I'll post the new log cat down here as a answer..

Comment: Why are you talking about "build path"? Please can you check you are adding the libraries here: http://postimage.org/image/6okoel5yx/ ? Sorry for my english

Comment: i did as you told me (actually, i never did as you told me) and now on the console there is this error: 
[2013-02-07 16:38:59 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/Base64Variant;
[2013-02-07 16:38:59 - Mobile] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/Base64Variant;

Comment: :) What says now is that you have this class added twice, may be you have 1 or more projects that includes this class added? Just fint it ;). Also re-clean all your projects in the workspace for avoid problems

Comment: ok, i'll fix it.. By the way, thank you very much! you've been very helpful! :)

Comment: So if this answer correct, please, mark it and other users can have a way to follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like you have not registered "RecognitionActivity" activity in manifest file.

Comment: yes, it results added to the Manifest! <activity android:name="com.example.mobile.RecognitionActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_recognition" > </activity>

Comment: activity not in manifest gives a very different exception. irrelevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Manifest file mention your activity name and action for it and also category .
2. In your Activity mention your starting contentview and mention your view id's in the activity.